# Trying to place my bullet points in the middle of page while making list left-align

Tags: html, css, html-lists, bulletedlist

Trying to center my bullet points in the middle of the page while left-aligning my list. Right now, my list is looking like this.

**HTML**

```
<ul style="list-style-type:none;">
  <li><b>exercitation :</b> consectetur adipiscing elit</li>
  <li><b>minima :</b> aliquip ex ea commodo consequat</li>
  <li><b>commodi consequatur:</b> magni dolores eos</li>
</ul>
```

**CSS**

```
ul {
  text-align: center;
  list-style-position: inside;
}
```

**Run the code snippet below.**

```css
ul {
  text-align: center;
  /* When I center this it looks like this whereas I want this in the middle but I want it to be centered and left-align. How do I achieve this? */
  list-style-position: inside;
}

li {
  /* text-align: left; */
}
```

```html
<ul style="list-style-type:none;">
  <li><b>exercitation :</b> consectetur adipiscing elit</li>
  <li><b>minima :</b> aliquip ex ea commodo consequat</li>
  <li><b>commodi consequatur:</b> magni dolores eos</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

Set `text-align: center;` on the container of the list (in this case - `body`), display the list as an `inline-block`, and align the contents of the list to the left.

```css
body {
  text-align: center;
}

ul {
  display: inline-block;
  list-style-position: inside;
  text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<ul style="list-style-type:none;">
  <li><b>exercitation :</b> consectetur adipiscing elit</li>
  <li><b>minima :</b> aliquip ex ea commodo consequat</li>
  <li><b>commodi consequatur:</b> magni dolores eos</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can manage by adding parent block to ul and `margin: auto;` will sets margin based on available width, please find below code snippet:

```css
ul {
  text-align: left;
  list-style-position: inside;
}

.parent {
    text-align: center;
    margin: auto;
    width: 80%;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">

  <ul>
      <li><b>exercitation :</b> consectetur adipiscing elit</li>
      <li><b>minima :</b> aliquip ex ea commodo consequat</li>
      <li><b>commodi consequatur:</b> magni dolores eos</li>
  </ul>
    
</div>
```